# Scope variable not changing after ajax post request

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, angularjs, laravel

I'm making a Yahtzee SPA. Here's my js file

```
var game = angular.module('yahtzee',[]);

game.controller('RollDicesController', function($scope, $http) {
  $scope.img1 = "style/img/dice1.jpg";
  $scope.img2 = "style/img/dice2.jpg";
  $scope.img3 = "style/img/dice3.jpg";
  $scope.img4 = "style/img/dice4.jpg";
  $scope.img5 = "style/img/dice5.jpg"; 

 $scope.result = {
     Ones : '0',
     Twos : '0',
     Threes : '0',
     Fours : '0',
     Fives : '0',
     Sixes : '0',
     ThreeOfAKind : '0',
     FourOfAKind : '0',
     FullHouse : '0',
     SmallStraight : '0',
     LargeStraight : '0',
     Chance: '0',
     Yahtzee : '0'
 };

 $scope.notSorted = function(obj){
     if (!obj) {
         return [];
     }
     return Object.keys(obj);
 }

 $scope.rollDices = function() {
     $dice1 = Math.floor((Math.random() * 6) + 1);
     $dice2 = Math.floor((Math.random() * 6) + 1);
     $dice3 = Math.floor((Math.random() * 6) + 1);
     $dice4 = Math.floor((Math.random() * 6) + 1);
     $dice5 = Math.floor((Math.random() * 6) + 1);

     $scope.img1 = "style/img/dice" + $dice1 + ".jpg";
     $scope.img2 = "style/img/dice" + $dice2 + ".jpg";
     $scope.img3 = "style/img/dice" + $dice3 + ".jpg";
     $scope.img4 = "style/img/dice" + $dice4 + ".jpg";
     $scope.img5 = "style/img/dice" + $dice5 + ".jpg";

     $http.post('calculate', {'dice1': $dice1, 'dice2': $dice2, 'dice3': $dice3, 'dice4': $dice4, 'dice5': $dice5 }).success(function(data) {
         $scope.result = data;
     }).error(function(data, status) { 
         $scope.errors.push(status);
     });

  };

});
```

What the request does is pretty much attribute values to the according moves. I have a php controller connected to the `calculate` route (I'm using Laravel) that does all the math work.
Now the issue is that although I'm receiving the values correctly (I've tested this), my table isn't updating.

I already have a main div in my webpage that has the controller defined:

```
<div ng-controller="RollDicesController">
    <div id="game_div">
        <div id="dice_div">
            <ul>
              <li style="list-style-type: none;" class="listaDados"  >
               <img id="dice1" ng-src="{{img1}}">
               <img id="dice2" ng-src="{{img2}}" > 
               <img id="dice3" ng-src="{{img3}}" > 
               <img id="dice4" ng-src="{{img4}}" >
               <img id="dice5" ng-src="{{img5}}" > 
              </li>
            </ul>
            <a>  
                <button id="rolldice_button" class= "button_class" ng-click="rollDices()">
                    Roll Dice!
                </button>
            </a>  
    <div id="table_div">
        <table id="score_table" border="1" >
            <tr ng-repeat="key in notSorted(result) track by $index" ng-init="val = result[key]">
                <td> {{ key }} </td>
                <td> {{ val }} </td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </div>
</div>
```

And for some reason, the table never changes, although `$scope.result` and the dice images do.

I really don't understand what I'm doing wrong, so I need your help.

Edit 1: I've found that after deleting this:

```
     $scope.result = {
     Ones : '0',
     Twos : '0',
     Threes : '0',
     Fours : '0',
     Fives : '0',
     Sixes : '0',
     ThreeOfAKind : '0',
     FourOfAKind : '0',
     FullHouse : '0',
     SmallStraight : '0',
     LargeStraight : '0',
     Chance: '0',
     Yahtzee : '0'
 };
```

I pressed the button and it worked once, and the following clicks didn't change the table.
For some reason after I give `$scope.result` a value, its value never changes again. Since my knowledge on AngularJS is limited, I have no idea why this is happening

Edit 2: I've tried changing the request using $scope.apply(), like this

```
$http.post('calculate', {'dice1': $dice1, 'dice2': $dice2, 'dice3': $dice3, 'dice4': $dice4, 'dice5': $dice5 }).success(function(data) {
            $scope.result = data;
            $scope.apply();
    }).error(function(data, status) { 
        $scope.errors.push(status);
    });
```

Edit 3: `$scope.$apply` was poorly written in my previous edit, and after correcting it, it now presents me with this error

`Error: error:inprog
Action Already In Progress
$digest already in progress`

Final edit: The $timeout worked, the problem was using the notSorted function.

The table is now created like this:

```
        <div id="table_div">
        <table id="score_table" border="1" >
            <tr ng-repeat="(key, val) in result track by $index">
                <td> {{ key }} </td>
                <td> {{ val }} </td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </div>
```

Although it's not sorted in the way I want it, at least it works.

Comment: Why do you need the `notSorted()` function? use a promise on the ajax call and attach the result model to the repeater

Comment: @LozCheroneツ can you please provide an example on how to do that? I'm fairly new to AngularJS

Comment: @LozCheroneツ i found another way to sort the table

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this instead, recommended over using $apply.

Note I inject $timeout at the top.

```
var game = angular.module('yahtzee',[]);

game.controller('RollDicesController', function($scope, $http, $timeout) {
  $scope.img1 = "style/img/dice1.jpg";
  $scope.img2 = "style/img/dice2.jpg";
  $scope.img3 = "style/img/dice3.jpg";
  $scope.img4 = "style/img/dice4.jpg";
  $scope.img5 = "style/img/dice5.jpg"; 

 $scope.result = {
     Ones : '0',
     Twos : '0',
     Threes : '0',
     Fours : '0',
     Fives : '0',
     Sixes : '0',
     ThreeOfAKind : '0',
     FourOfAKind : '0',
     FullHouse : '0',
     SmallStraight : '0',
     LargeStraight : '0',
     Chance: '0',
     Yahtzee : '0'
 };

 $scope.notSorted = function(obj){
     if (!obj) {
         return [];
     }
     return Object.keys(obj);
 }

 $scope.rollDices = function() {
     $dice1 = Math.floor((Math.random() * 6) + 1);
     $dice2 = Math.floor((Math.random() * 6) + 1);
     $dice3 = Math.floor((Math.random() * 6) + 1);
     $dice4 = Math.floor((Math.random() * 6) + 1);
     $dice5 = Math.floor((Math.random() * 6) + 1);

     $scope.img1 = "style/img/dice" + $dice1 + ".jpg";
     $scope.img2 = "style/img/dice" + $dice2 + ".jpg";
     $scope.img3 = "style/img/dice" + $dice3 + ".jpg";
     $scope.img4 = "style/img/dice" + $dice4 + ".jpg";
     $scope.img5 = "style/img/dice" + $dice5 + ".jpg";

     $http.post('calculate', {'dice1': $dice1, 'dice2': $dice2, 'dice3': $dice3, 'dice4': $dice4, 'dice5': $dice5 }).success(function(data) {
         $timeout(function() {
             $scope.result = data;
         });
     }).error(function(data, status) { 
         $scope.errors.push(status);
     });

  };

});
```

Comment: it says $timeout isn't defined

Comment: Did you inject it in the controller definition? See 
game.controller('RollDicesController', function($scope, $http, $timeout) { . You need to put it in there like I did in my code.

Comment: oh sorry, I only noticed it now. Will do.

Answer (score 0):

Try below code:

```
<div id="table_div">
        <table id="score_table" border="1" >
            <tr ng-repeat="key in result track by $index" ng-init="val = result[key]">
                <td> {{ key }} </td>
                <td> {{ val }} </td>
            </tr>
        </table>
</div>
```

Or try this:

```
$http.post('calculate', {'dice1': $dice1, 'dice2': $dice2, 'dice3': $dice3, 'dice4': $dice4, 'dice5': $dice5 }).success(function(data) {
         $timeout(function() {
             $scope.result = data;
         });
     }).error(function(data, status) { 
         $scope.errors.push(status);
     });
$timeout to avoid $digest error.
```

Comment: this makes no sense, I need the notSorted function in order to have my array in the order I want

Comment: then try second option which i have given above.